# Get Action arguments similar to webapi in mvc action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have an API method that accept a `Dictionary<string, object>` that is returned from `HttpActionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments` property (used within a WebApi action filter). I need to construct a similar dictionary from `ActionExecutedContext` in a MVC action filter so that I can use same API call from the mvc filter as well.

I tried several approaches but they are not very straitforward. If there is easy way to construct the actionArguments dictionary from ActionExecutedContext   please let me know.

```
    //webapi - working fine
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Call_A(context.ActionContext.ActionArguments)        
    }

    //mvc- need to find a way to get argument dictionary
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Call_A(context.?)        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this exists for `OnActionExecuted`, but it definitely exists for `OnActionExecuting`.   If you do need it on Executed (if it doesn't exist, I don't think it does) then you can store it in the filter temporarily, eg:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> actionParams { get; set; }

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    this.actionParams = context.ActionParameters;
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    foreach (var param in this.actionParams) {
        // param.Key
        // param.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was aware about the ActionParameters in ActionExecutingContext. But did't have any idea how to use it. Your approach sounds reasonable.

Comment: I believe that this code is bugged because your class level variable actionParams is shared by all requests/threads. By the time request 1 enter OnActionExecuted, request 2 may have already changed the actionParams variable.

Comment: Now at least in Web API 2 you have the ability to simply use actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments

Comment: Only 1 instance of the class is created; not 1 instance per service call. I just confirmed this by calling an action method twice simultaneously.

Comment: `private Dictionary<string, object> dict;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            dict = actionContext.ActionArguments;
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            _logger.Debug(dict.Values.First());
        }`

First request is "A", second is "B". But "B" gets logged twice.